# Make bold text inside element (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make text (fat) bold. Curretly I managed to do this whit code below:

```
Movie <b>fat</b> was been added
```

But this **bold** tags won't work. Now the question is how to enable html for only (fat), to be bold like this: `Movie` **fat** `was been added`

*My code so far:*

```
var boldy = (Movie[0].title)
var fat = boldy.bold()

$("div.container div:first").text("Movie " + (fat) + " was been added")
```

I also tried whit this:

```
$("div.container div:first").html("Hello <b>"+(boldy)+"</b>")
```

Comment: The second example `.html(...)` works. Is `Movie[0].title` defined / empty string?

Comment: Second example returns empty string, yes and nothing happens.

Comment: so... is `Movie[0].title` empty? What does `console.log(boldy);` print?

Comment: My first example applys <b> like it should. But html inside .text() is not working.

Comment: @Shasher It's not a bug, it's a feature - `.text()` does not render HTML - that's why you have `.html()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var word ="fat"
$("div:first").html("Movie <b>"+word+"</b> was been added")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is the same example that its in my code. I have tried that whit array variable, but no results.

Comment: Now Im a bit confused, can you make a example of array and whats ur expected result?

Comment: Its working now `.html("Movie <b>"+(word)+"</b> was been added")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$("div.container div:first").css("font-weight","Bold");
```

That will change the property **font-weight** from that div to **bold**.

@EDIT: You can make a div with an ID and set that ID on the jQuery mention:

```
$("div.container div:first div#text").css("font-weight","Bold");
```

Comment: Nope, OP only wants part of the content bold.

Comment: I want only part of text to be bold.

Comment: @Slasher I just edited as you wanted. Is it variable or the movie name only? If it is the movie name only, you can have the movie name with a different tag.

Comment: Have you done a div surrounding the place you're placing the variable?
(example: `Movie <div id="text">fat</div> was been added`)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var world = 'world';
$("div").html(`Hello <b>${world}</b>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Movie fat was been added
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = $("div.container div:first").html;
$("div.container div:first").html(html.replace(/fat/gi, '<strong>$& </strong>'));
```